# How do I use a global variable in the same Mongodb script JS file

Tags: mongodb

I have my JS file.
I have a variable declared at the top called:

```
var aCollection = db.myCollection;
```

I use this variable to refer to the collection. It's easy, since I can change the name of the collection to process another collection.

Now I want to use this in a function, like this:

```
fn1 = function(_id) {

    // use  _id and aCollection 

    // i get an error if I use "aCollection"
}
```

And I call the above function like this:

```
db.eval(fn1, "245");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.eval` executes `fn1` on the server in a separate context so it doesn't have access to the global context of its containing script.  You'd have to change `fn1` to accept `aCollection` as a parameter and then pass that parameter into your `db.eval` call.

Comment: Which comes to my second question.

I'm not able to send the second parameter, i.e. the collection name.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515580/mongodb-how-do-i-pass-a-collection-parameter-to-use