# Mongodb: How do I pass a 'collection' parameter to use?

Tags: mongodb

I have my JS file. I have a variable declared at the top called:

```js
var aCollection = db.myCollection;
```

I have a stored JS procedure which takes in two parameters. A string "id" and the "collection " to use.

How do I pass two parameters, and that too a collection as a parameter?

```js
db.eval("runSP('32', aCollection");
```

If I do the above, then I get an exception saying that "aCollection" doesn't exist.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just doing a javascript concat?

```js
db.eval("runSP('32', '"+aCollection+"')"(;
```

Sanity check for concatenation of the collection variable with strings:

```js
> use test
switched to db test
> show collections
system.indexes
system.js
> var aCollection = db.system.js;
> print ("foo" + aCollection + "bar");
footest.system.jsbar
```

Your function would receive the string name of the collection. If thats all your function is expecting, then you are good. If you need to resolve the collection inside your javascript function, you can do:

```js
function runSP(numberVal, aCollection) {
    var coll = db[aCollection];
    coll.find();
}
```

Comment: This would only work if `aCollection` is a string though.  In this case `aCollection` is a collection object.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Not true. It still evaluates as a string value when you concat. Test it.

Comment: What I meant was that it wouldn't work if the stored function was expecting aCollection to be a collection object.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Correct. I don't know how the OP uses the value. If its being used as a collection object, I just updated my answer to show how to easily resolve it.

Comment: Can I pass a 'cursor' object to a stored procedure?

Comment: @user1455545: I don't believe so, but I could be wrong. Stored js functions have to be executed by passing a string for evaluation. But there is nothing stopping you from passing values and creating a cursor within the function.

Answer (score 0):

`db.eval` can take multiple parameters that are passed into the function that's provided as the first parameter:

```
db.eval(runSP, '32', aCollection);
```

Comment: I think this approach only applies to when you run a code object directly, and not when using stored javascript procedures. All of the stored procedures seem to require a javascript string to be eval'd: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Storingfunctionsserverside

Comment: Ah, this question was a followup to an earlier question of the OP and I didn't notice he switched to using a stored function.  Thanks.

Comment: So how do I pass a 'collection' parameter to a stored procedure?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't.  Which is a good indication you may be doing something a bit outside of best practice.

Comment: ok, then how do I pass the parameter that I'll pass to 'find' inside the SP?
I think I'm passing the string well, but it's just bombing.


For ex:
I'm passing a string parameter like this to the SP:

"{{ 'key1' : 'e9c' }, { 'ver' : 1 }}"

Then in the SP, I do this:
db.test.find(tojson(passed_string));

Now it just doesn't work.

Comment: @user: I think you're close, but if `tojson` does what it sounds like it does, you're going the wrong way...use `JSON.parse` there instead.

Comment: I get this error if I use JSON.parse::

uncaught exception: {
 "errno" : -3,
 "errmsg" : "invoke failed: JS Error: ReferenceError: JSON is not defined nofile_b:7",
 "ok" : 0
}